# Can you suggest some good ETW readers?

Tags: etw

I'm currently using Microsoft Network Monitor to parse thru debug event traces. It is not a bad tool, but not very good either. Do you know some better solutions?

Answer (score 6):

These are readers for exploring custom ETW traces:

- [SvcPerf](http://svcperf.codeplex.com/) - End-to-End ETW trace viewer for manifest based traces
- [LINQPad](http://www.linqpad.net/) + [Tx (LINQ for Logs and traces)](http://www.linqpad.net/#db) driver - Simple reader that allows you to query ETW traces
- [PerfView](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=28567) - multitool that allows you to do amost everything with ETW, but not particularly user-friendly

Answer (score 3):

PerfView http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=28567

Answer (score 2):

If you're after giving graphic visualization of traces for the sake of performance analysis, you may use the following:
 1. [Windows Reliability and Performance Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc755081%28WS.10%29.aspx) which is an MMC snap-in and is easy to use for basic analysis (locally, from the server)
 2. [xperf](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pigscanfly/archive/2008/02/09/xperf-a-new-tool-in-the-windows-sdk.aspx), which is a stand-alone tool from the [Windows Performance Tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/performance/cc825801.aspx). 
  **Xperf** itself is a command-line tool for captures and processing traces and **Xperfview** allows creating graphs and tables from the captured data. Look at [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pigscanfly/archive/2008/02/16/using-xperf-to-take-a-trace.aspx) for an overview.
 3. Visual Studio 2010 profiler contains a "Concurrency Visualizer" which is actually a nice tool to collect and visualize ETW traces, specifically tailored around analysis of thread contention issues (but can also be used to analyze network traces, I think). See this [blog post](http://www.wintellect.com/CS/blogs/jrobbins/archive/2009/10/23/vs-2010-beta-2-concurrency-visualizer-profiling-in-depth-first-look.aspx) on using the tool and also you may use the underlying tools directly: [VSPerfCmd](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182403.aspx) and [VSPerfReport](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182405.aspx).

Comment: Wow this "Concurrency Visualizer" looks great. Unfortunately I'm looking for tool that will parse and present my custom traces, not this supplied by system.

Answer (score 1):

I like to use Log Parser [[link](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=24659)] to parse through the logs for the events that I am most interested in.  I love the SQL-like query structure.